# Visual Studio 2015 adds namespace in front of class name

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015

I'm having a problem with auto insert namespace in front of class when I hit `'('` of Visual Studio 2015 like that:

```
namespace SimpleClasses2
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Car myCar = new SimpleClasses2.Car();
        }
    }

    class Car
    {
        public string Make { get; set; }
        public string Model { get; set; }
    }
}
```

What I want is: `Car myCar = new Car();`

But when I hit `'('` so I get automatically: `Car myCar = new SimpleClass2.Car();`

I try to fix it with light bulb but when I start with new project I meet this problem again. I don't want have namespace in front of class name.

Comment: Do you have other `Car` types defined elsewhere?

Comment: Hi you.
No, that is all my code.

Comment: Your current code looks correct. `SimpleClasses2` qualifier is unneeded and should be colored grey in VisualStudio to indicate an unnecessary qualifier. Simply remove the qualifier and it should work.

Comment: If you delete `SimpleClass2.`, do you get any warnings/highlights on `Car`?

Comment: This happens to me a lot too - I think it's a bug in Visual Studio. Are you running Update 3?

Comment: Unbelievable. My VS2015 even suggests **'name can be simplified'**.

Comment: @Dai: Yes. Are the anyway to fix it? :(

Comment: @LeiYang: metoo, there is a light bulb with this suggest

Comment: @JohnG: Thank you! But I don't want to remove it myself because I don't type it.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever: if I delete `SimpleClass2.`, there are no warnings/highlights on `Car`